# Adding NavigationController to TabBar based app programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have 6 viewControllers in a customTabBar based app. TabbBar added programmatically.
Now I'd like to add a navigationcontroller in order to push detail view controllers getting benefits from navigationBar, but keeping the TabBar below as main way to navigate in the entire app.

with this code I obtain the first uiviewcontroller "FirstVC" with navigation bar on screen, but I cannot "push" the detail "FirstDetail1VC" view controller(s) from a test button

in my  AppDelegate:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

let myTabController = CustomTabbarController()

window?.rootViewController = myTabController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

in my1VC (giving message "cannot push UINavigationController") :

```
func showNextVc() {

    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if let newViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstDetail1VC") as? FirstDetail1VC {

        let navigator = MyMainNavController {
            navigator.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

after update in CustomTabbarController:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let my1VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstVC")
let my2VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC")
let my3VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdVC")
let my4VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FourthVC")
let my5VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FifthVC")
let my6VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SixthVC")

my2VC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "second", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
my3VC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "third", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
my4VC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "fourth", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
my5VC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "fifth", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
my6VC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "sixth", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)

let controllers = [my1VC, my2VC, my3VC, my4VC,my5VC, my6VC]


// if I use this one, text titles appears on tab bar, but cannot use navigation controller
viewControllers = controllers

// if I use this I have the navigation controlelr working but     
tabBarbuttons not showing text title
// self.viewControllers = controllers.map {
// UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)
// }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert UINavigationController inside UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921027/how-to-insert-uinavigationcontroller-inside-uitabbarcontroller)

Comment: There are already good tutorial about your question: https://medium.com/@ITZDERR/uinavigationcontroller-and-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically-swift-3-d85a885a5fd0 or https://www.ios-blog.com/tutorials/quick-tips/add-uinavigationcontroller-to-uitabbarcontroller-programatically/ for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign UINavigationController to each UIViewController when set array of all ViewControllers.

```
//Add NavigationController to all VC
viewControllers = [start, my1VC, my2VC, my3VC, my4VC,my5VC, my6VC].map {
    UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)
}
```

Comment: this works! but now the tabBar does not shows button title anymore until I click on them once

Comment: You have to set image to tabBarItem also

Comment: even using         my2VC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "2", image: nil, tag: 1) title is not appearing, otherwise, if I don't map the array, titles appears since first app start

Comment: UITabBarItem(title: "", image: ic_home, selectedImage: ic_home_filled)

Comment: You need to set Selected and Unselected image icon to tabBarItem

Comment: I added updated code, but issue remains, now I have no image to use but cannot understand why titles are not appearing

Comment: You can not set "nil". You compulsory set image to tabBarItem. Otherwise what is the purpose to show only text??!!

Comment: oh, I using the text showed or not as parameter if code is working or not, so map/ not  map is all an expected behavior?

Comment: ok, using system icon for testing, all working! thanks a lot!

Comment: May be... I am not sure but TabBarItem working well after adding icon.